# Jquery Table Sorter slow issue for more than 3000 data rows

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, tablesorter

I am using Jquery table sorter for sort my data. Currently My db table has more than 3000 rows when load this data(PHP/MySQL) using jquery table sorter, page getting slower, what can i do for it, I am searching a solution using jquery or mysql/php?

Currently I am load 20 rows per page

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use sorttable javascript library which is faster than jquery table sorter.Documentation is here http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/